# Using array in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

I'm using [google-maps-for-rails (gmap4rails)](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails). The gem has a method that created an array to use in javascript.

```
hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
 marker.lat user.latitude
 marker.lng user.longitude
end
```

This results in the following:

```
[{:lat=>33.462209, :lng=>-86.812519, :infowindow=>"hello"}]
```

or simpler to read

```
[
  {
   :lat => 33.462209,
   :lng => -86.812519,
   :infowindow => "hello"
  }
]
```

I am trying to use this in coffeescript, but where I pass this array into the coffeescript from a variable in my controller. (I am using [Paloma JS](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) for page-specific js, where you can access controller variables in your coffeescript.)

I've tried to convert the array into JSON and used `gsub` to replace characters, but I've been having difficulty.

In specific, I tried to convert to JSON then remove the commas, `hash.to_json.gsub(/,/, '')`, which outputs

```
[{"lat":33.462209"lng":-86.812519"infowindow":"hello"}]
```

I think I need to remove the brackets, `{` and `}` here, and possibly include the proper line indentions for coffeescript.

In the end, it should look like this:

```
[
  lat: 33.462209
  lng: -86.812519
  infowindow: "hello"
]
```

Any ideas?? Thanks for the time.

Comment: The 'array' you say you require in the end is not an array. Are you really sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to convert the array into JSON and used gsub to replace characters, but I've been having difficulty.

You should just use the JSON you're producing, as it is. It's completely valid CoffeeScript. There is no reason at all to try to strip anything out of it.

The CoffeeScript you're trying to produce is actually identical anyways. This...

```
[
  lat: 33.462209
  lng: -86.812519
  infowindow: "hello"
]
```

is really `[{ lat: ..., lng: ..., }]`, with the commas and `{}` *hidden* but still syntactically present. CoffeeScript allows you to omit the `{}` when defining an object literal, but it's *still* an object literal, and you gain nothing by stripping them out of your JSON. Either way, the structure you're producing will be identical: An array, containing one element, which is an object, containing properties lat/lng/infowindow.